# How to make this calendar plugin responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4

You can view the test version of my calendar plugin [here](http://studyspot-env.2hzp7aa3t3.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/profile/schedule/) . Note how it is not responsive. 
Notice how it is supposed to be responsive when you decrease or increase the width of your browser if you look at the example on the maker's page [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/jquery/full-calendar/).

My code:

```
  <!-- Section: Calendar -->
  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
        <div id="calendar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

And the site's example code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="calendar-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously my calendar doesn't become smaller when I decrease my browser's width, but the example does! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed width applied in `room_detail.css` of 800px  on line 13- it should be a percentage or have media queries specifying appropriate widths

```
section {
  height: 70%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 800px; /* This is what's causing the problem */
}
```

Remove it or change it to a percentage and it should work - you may need to apply media queries to have it behave as you'd like.